# Posting Date Info From MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage that I am looking to feed event info from a MySQL Database. I have a PHP function delivering this event info and am trying to include the event's datetime but I want to format it using the `date_format`function in mysql.

The PHP funciton as I have currently tried is as follows;

```
function eventbox() {
    $events = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM my_db.events LEFT JOIN my_db.venues USING (venue_id) LEFT JOIN my_db.eventtype USING (eventtype_id),'); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($events)) { 
        $loopResult .= ' 
                <div class="eventbox">
                    <div class="eventtitle">'.$row['eventname'].'</div>
                    <div class="eventdate">'.date_format($row ('eventtime'), 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y').'</div>  
                    <div class="eventvenue">'.$row['name'].'</div>
                    <div class="tie-inbuttonholder">
                        <button type="button">tie-in</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eventboxicon" class="tie-inbutton">'.$row['eventicon'].'</div> 
                </div>  
        '; 
    } 
    echo $loopResult;
}
```

I basically want to grab the DateTime row from the table and present it in the format of "Monday May 19th 2014 at 7:00PM"

If there is anyone who can shed light on this and how to complete the function properly that would be super helpful!

UPDATE/EDIT:

So I have updated the function with some help from @Prior and have gotten it feeding information and filling all the `<divs>` except for `<div class="eventdate">`on the page again. The function now reads:

```
function eventbox() {
$loopResult = "";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT eventname, name, eventicon, DATE_FORMAT(eventtime, '%a %b %dth %Y at %h:%i%p') FROM my_db.events LEFT JOIN my_db.venues USING (venue_id) LEFT JOIN my_db.eventtype USING (eventtype_id)"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $loopResult .= ' 
            <div class="eventbox">
                <div class="eventtitle">'.$row['eventname'].'</div>
                <div class="eventdate">'.$row['DATE_FORMAT(eventtime)'].'</div>  
                <div class="eventvenue">'.$row['name'].'</div>
                <div class="tie-inbuttonholder">
                    <button type="button">tie-in</button>
                </div>
                <div class="eventboxicon" class="tie-inbutton">'.$row['eventicon'].'</div> 
            </div>  
    '; 
}
echo $loopResult;
}
```

Now the only issue is that when I run the script I get the error code;

> Notice: Undefined index: DATE_FORMAT(eventtime) in /var/www/test/test_func.inc.php on line 23

And line 23 would be:

```
<div class="eventdate">'.$row['DATE_FORMAT(eventtime)'].'</div>
```

I have tried a number of different ways of formatting this part of the function including
(that being said i do get slightly different errors running the `.date_format($row...` methods);

```
<div class="eventdate">'.date_format($row ('eventtime'), 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y').'</div>
<div class="eventdate">'.date_format($row ['eventtime'], '%a %b %dth %Y at %h:%i%p').'</div>
<div class="eventdate">'.date_format($row['eventtime'], 'l M d\t\h Y \a\t g:iA').'</div>
<div class="eventdate">'.$row['DATE_FORMAT(eventtime, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y')'].'</div>
etc...
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to correct this issue? When I run the SQL query against my server I get a great table that works perfectly, and all other parts of the function work great.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean using date_format function of PHP?

Comment: so what error you getting

Comment: You are using wrong brackets It should be `$row ['eventtime']` instead of `$row ('eventtime')`

Comment: @Prior tried with both square and round brackets no luck ..

Comment: What error is it reporting?

Comment: Also, there is a trailing comma at the end of your SQL-Query. Is this query even working?

Comment: This query was working perfectly until i changed from a manually inputted date system (seperate tables for day, month, year, etc) to a datetime system. and now that I have removed some of the field and added others the query does not seem to work... @Prior

Comment: Have you tried my solution? If you gave up using date_format for mysql, use the one in PHP

Comment: @kimbarcelona yes just gave it a shot, unfortunately doesnt seem to be the problem! thanks for the suggestion tho!

Comment: "I basically want to grab the DateTime row from the table and present it in the format of "Monday May 19th 2014 at 7:00PM" - is what you say so i gave you a simple solution.. I'm now lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format-string you are looking for is `%a %b %dth %Y at %h:%i%p` ([Consult the Mysql-Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)).
So your whole SQL-Query would look like this (I ignored your trailing comma at the end of the query):

```
SELECT eventname, name, DATE_FORMAT(eventtime, '%a %b %dth %Y at %h:%i%p`') FROM my_db.events LEFT JOIN my_db.venues USING (venue_id) LEFT JOIN my_db.eventtype USING (eventtype_id)
```

Please also note the following:

1. You are using the wrong type of brackets where you retrieve the data in PHP: It should be `$row ['eventtime']` instead of `$row ('eventtime')`
2. Function MySQL ist deprecated in PHP, Please use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Your whole code would look like this:

```
function eventbox() {
    $loopResult = "";
    $mysqli = ... //Initialize Databaseconenction here
    $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT eventname, name, DATE_FORMAT(eventtime, '%a %b %dth %Y at %h:%i%p`') FROM my_db.events LEFT JOIN my_db.venues USING (venue_id) LEFT JOIN my_db.eventtype USING (eventtype_id)"); 
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($eventname, $name, $eventtime);
    while($query->fetch()) {
        $loopResult .= ' 
                <div class="eventbox">
                    <div class="eventtitle">'.$eventname.'</div>
                    <div class="eventdate">'.$eventtime.'</div>  
                    <div class="eventvenue">'.$name.'</div>
                    <div class="tie-inbuttonholder">
                        <button type="button">tie-in</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eventboxicon" class="tie-inbutton">'.$row['eventicon'].'</div> 
                </div>  
        '; 
    }
    $query->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    echo $loopResult;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to incorporate the MySQL query you suggest here into my existing function layout but am running into syntax issues.

Comment: nothing specific. I have no error codes programmed into this function so when i run the query on an html page it just comes back blank. fills out no divs. this was working a few hours ago when i was using a different method of filling the time info.. hmm

Comment: When I completely replaced my function with yours it fundamentally changed my page, removed my sidebar, which is on a completely different z-index on the page?? not sure why that happened.

Comment: Without any more details, nobody will be able to help you. If there are no PHP-Errors, I guess the query is not fetching any data at all? Is your table empty maybe? Or did you switch of error-reporting?

Comment: Yeah, fair enough, just seems odd, I really appreciate the help, you seem to definitely be on the right track. The table isn't empty and I haven't switched off error reporting, the only time ive ever gotten errors through PHP is when ive coded them in to echo back.. would I need to do that here? beginner question I know haha.

Comment: Maybe error-reporting is switched of in your php.ini Try including the following in top of your script: `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Results!! `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/test/test_func.inc.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined variable: loopResult in /var/www/test/test_func.inc.php on line 31`

Comment: line 18: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($events)) { `
line 31: ` echo $loopResult;`

Comment: I'd suggest that you dive deeper into PHP and learn using Mysqli.

Comment: It seems as if the query is failing (maybe because of the trailing comma at then end?) Try using `echo(mysql_error());` After your query to see whats wrong.

Comment: Hey I got this going pretty well! thanks for all your help, your initial MySQL query was the breaking point to figuring it out! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have solution here that can present it in the format you want but using PHP date_format function. This is easier. And also use brackets instead of parenthesis.

Change this line:

```
<div class="eventdate">'.date_format($row ('eventtime'), 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y').'</div>
```

to:

```
 <div class="eventdate">'.date_format($row['eventtime'], 'l M d\t\h Y \a\t g:iA').'</div>
```

Comment: `$row ('eventtime')` is not valid, should be `$row ['eventtime']`

Comment: Will this even work with an SQL-DATETIME? Or will it just work with PHP DateTimes?

Comment: Yes, this works in the datetime format of MYSQL. So for example: 2010-10-25 18:03:35 will give us Monday Oct 25th 2010 at 6:03PM